# Is there a way to schedule tweets using Python, without having to run the code 24*7 or applying for Twitter Ads API?

Tags: python, twitter, scheduling, tweets

I'm trying to build a Twitter bot that sends out tweets at scheduled times. I'm unable to find a way to do this without either using Python to keep the code running forever or applying for Twitter Ads API which isn't possible for a personal project like mine.
I would appreciate any help/suggestions that would allow me to accomplish this. Thank you!

Comment: You can put code on remote server and set up OS to execute your python script at certain time.

Comment: If you have a python script, then you can use `crontab` to add a scheduler to your OS that will run your script every x (minutes/seconds/hours)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.